# What is this small plant with tiny white flowers and tiny saw-teethed leaves?

Tags: identification

I got a small plant (from my mother-in-law... ) on which I would like to have an ID with your help. I cannot say much about its life-cycle as I only got it recently: she told me it was once in a pot and she put it outside. Thus I assume it survived winters with peaks down to -20 C.

- tiny white flowers (1.5cm in diameter)
- saw-teethed leaves (2cm long, 1.5 large, reminds me of birch-leaves)
- flowers die back quite fast (a few days), but new one are coming out again quickly

Some images (*click to enlarge*)

[image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Looks like some species of campanula like [Campanula carpatica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campanula_carpatica)

Comment: How tall is the whole plant?

Comment: @Bamboo I haven't added the plant-size, because I can't really say. I have two of them, one is 20x20x15cm the other one has only one flower-carrying stem... IOW: it seems to vary a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like some species of campanula like [Campanula carpatica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campanula_carpatica).

This spring I recieved one campanula carpatica as a gift in a pot. 
I planted it outside in June as it was overgrowing the pot and I heard it can withstand the colds of the winter.

I can't say it has been doing great outside, but it is still alive.

Answer (score 3):

It is [Campanula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campanula), but its not *C. carpatica* - it looks remarkably like [*C. trachelium* 'album plenum'](http://skalnicky-jundrov.webnode.cz/album/trvalky/campanula-trachelium-album-plenum-jpg/), the so called 'nettle leaved' campanula, but that has flower stems which reach 80 cm, which is why I asked about the height...